# Mapping XML to another XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, transformer-model

Our system acts as a middleware between several different systems. This requires working with several differently formatted and laid out XML files that contain (roughly) the same information. Currently this is handled via middleware knowing about all of those formats. This is becoming unmanageable and we want to replace it with a path which allows our system to just work with the standard format, and convert our client files to and from using a transformer layer. However, we have a lot of clients coming on board (hence the rework), and would like to reduce the amount of extra developer work to a minimum per client.

On investigation, I can see three primary ways of doing this:

a) Use an XSLT transformer. Handle each client and XML file separately. Pros: very clear to understand, little overhead during runtime, simple text conversion, can be just dropped and uploaded, can largely be reused if client formats happen to be very similar. Cons: Requires a lot of work to get all XML files converted per client. Can technically be done by a non-developer.

b) Utilise AutoMapper: Create initial classes for our format, then run all client files through an XML -> POCO generator, and create profiles for each of them. Pros: Fairly simple to understand, maps could potentially be reused for different clients, strong typing for clarity and maintenance ease. Cons: Can only be done by developer, requires actual redeployment (I can't see us implementing a plugin system for that, but I can see it being a microservice).

c) Create a "visual" custom mapper and mapping engine. Use reflection to loop through properties and customize the mappings through a web-based interface. Expose this interface to customers and tell them which information they want mapped where after they have uploaded the XML and the system has autogenerated the POCOs. Pros: Very flexible, self-maintaining. Cons: Requires .... a LOT of work and time.

d) ??? Maybe something better?

So I'm trying to pick between one of those three, but not quite sure which one to go for. I'm starting to incline towards the XSLT because it'll technically allow anybody to do the transformation. Of course we would need to implement a verification system, but that's... an implementation detail.

Comment: it seems like you need to de-serialize the current xml to a class structure, copy properties to new class structure, serialize new class format which will be common for all formats.  It really depends on the differences between current format how much work is required.  If the differences is optional parameters then the work is very simple.  If the tag names are different for same properties then the work is more complicated.

Comment: The names _are_ different. The thing is that the XML structures can be very different, akin to what you would find in a complex data model that is projected to an equally complex view model, but having different names for mapping fields. What I need in the middle would be something like AutoMapper, but for XML. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I would read (de-serialize) xml into classes.  And then do the mapping in the classes.  I have never used AutoMapper but you may be able to use it on the classes.